# Why don't I see a yellow preview indicator when using the chamfer tool?

Tags: computer-aided-design, solidworks

I'm having problems trying to use chamfer on an edge. Typically I see yellow previews of how cuts/extrusions will appear, but this is not the case for my first time using chamfer. I have tried looking at tutorials in chamfer, I keep clicking on an edge, but the purple arrows that say flip sides only appears. On most YouTube tutorials the yellow indicators appear after; why don't I see the same thing?

[image: solidworks screen shot]

Comment: If you press the green check mark, does the chamfer appear in grey? If not, does it give you some kind of error? Also, since you don't actually need it on that shape, you might try unchecking 'tangent propagation.' The previews in solidworks are not always very reliable, but the feature itself should work correctly based on your screenshot.

Comment: just checking: roughly how large is your part? Chamfers can't be made if there isn't room for them.